# Laravel Form is not submit?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Hii friends i am new in laravel.

this is my code and this code is not working.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('dailyhourse.destroy', $value->id),'style'=>'display:inline')) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('dailyhourse.destroy', $value->id),'style'=>'display:inline')) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my controller code for destroy function.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    if ($this->dailyhourse->delete($id)) {
        return Redirect::route("{$this->url}.index")
                        ->with('success', 'Record deleted successfully.');
    } else {
        return Redirect::route("{$this->url}.index")
                        ->with('error', 'Record deleting error.');
    }
}
```

but in firebug the form is display but when i click on Delete button.

the form is not submit.

but when i click on submit button is not doing anything process.

not return any type of error or warning.

please help.

where i do mistake.

Comment: What's the generated html for the forms?

Comment: does it redirect when you see the blank page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see at this moment is that you might need to wrap style => display:inline in another array.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('dailyhourse.destroy', $value->id), array('style'=>'display:inline'))) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('dailyhourse.destroy', $value->id), array('style'=>'display:inline'))) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The form opening incorrectly can cause the form to become unsubmitable.
Give it a try, but it's the only thing I can see at this moment.